# Making table content responsive to screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

I am making a table with pictures and text content (four rows, five columns) and am looking for the best way to make the content adapt to a screen without having to scroll from left to right to read it. So on a laptop it will show up as five columns, but on a mobile screen probably one or two.

I have seen suggestions of making a bunch of containers, divs etc and manually making them align on the page like a table. I am unsure how to do this to achieve the same effect as my current table. I'd be appreciative of any help and suggestions!

Comment: [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) is the best for responsiveness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsBin demo - Responsive Table](http://jsbin.com/zedule/3/) (Without Bootstrap)***

Instead of telling you ***"...just use Bootstrap"*** (155KB of stuff you'll barely use and understand, and losing valuable time searching for *How-To's*)...

here's a small school how to ***think responsively*** and **actually understand the hell you're doing**.

### Think the *Mobile-First* way:

add to the header of your page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Inside your **CSS**, write code like you style for extra small devices `<768px(or higher)` **as default**.
So that whatever you write as *Default*, it will apply to all other (bigger) sizes **unless overwritten at some point inside a specific (higher) @media size** and added up as a `class`name to the same element:

```
/* ::: XS (Extra small devices ad up) so: DEFAULT STYLES! */
/*here*/
/* ::: SM (Tablets and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px){ /*here*/ }
/* ::: MD (Desktop and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) { /*here*/ }
/* ::: LG (Large desktop and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { /*here*/ }
```

*How the @media overwrite logic works while resizing?* This simple example will tell you all:

```
XS +------------------->
SM     +--------------->    
MD          +---------->
LG               +----->
```

```
<div class=".hide-xs">You'll never see me :(</div><!-- Will be hidden on all sizes! -->
<div class=".hide-xs .show-md">:)</div><!-- hidden on mobile(xs) and tablet(sm) but visible on Desktop(md) and Large desktop(lg) -->
```

inside CSS you only need to define `.hide-xs` inside the `XS` (not inside SM) and `.show-md` inside `MD` (not in LG, cause as we said, even if you go to extra large, the class `.show-md` applies to the *this-or-larger* rule.)

### Responsive table

Great let's see what you can do with your table:

- Use `DIV`! (instead of `table`)
- Design CSS as for mobile XS (keep all elements to `block`) as you would like to see them on mobile.
- Hide "headings" for XS, making them visible for SM (larger will be applied consequently too, remember?)
- For SM (*or-higher*) set your `display:` property of `.table` to `table`,  to `.row` to `table-row;` and immediate children of `.row > div` to `table-cell`

### Example:

```css
/* ::: GLOBALS */
*{margin:0; box-sizing:border-box;}
html, body{height:100%;}
body{font:100%/1.3 sans-serif; color:#444; overflow-y:scroll;}


/* ::: XS (Extra small devices and up) so: DEFAULT STYLES! */
.hide-xs{
  position:absolute;
  visibility:hidden;
}
.table img{
  width:100%;
}


/* ::: SM (Tablets and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .show-xs{
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
  }
  .hide-xs{
    position:initial;
    visibility:visible;
  }
  .table{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
    border-collapse:collapse;
  }
  .table .row{
    display:table-row;
  }
  .table .row > div{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
  }
}

/* ::: MD (Desktop and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) {}

/* ::: LG (Large desktop and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Responsive table example by Roko CB</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="table">

    <div class="row hide-xs">
      <div>Image</div>
      <div>Color</div>
      <div>Sample</div>
      <div>Desc</div>
      <div>Price</div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- ROW -->
    <div class="row">
      <!-- CELLS -->
      <div><img src="//placehold.it/170x80/faf"></div>
      <div><span class="show-xs">Color:</span> #faf</div>
      <div><span class="show-xs">Sample:</span> 170x80px</div>
      <div><span class="show-xs">Desc:</span> Pinky</div>
      <div><span class="show-xs">Price:</span> 2.13</div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- OK, you got it -->
    <div class="row">
      <div><img src="//placehold.it/170x80/ffa"></div>
      <div><span class="show-xs">Color:</span> #ffa</div>
      <div><span class="show-xs">Sample:</span> 170x80px</div>
      <div><span class="show-xs">Desc:</span> Yelly</div>
      <div><span class="show-xs">Price:</span> 1.90</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div><img src="//placehold.it/170x80/afa"></div>
      <div><span class="show-xs">Color:</span> #afa</div>
      <div><span class="show-xs">Sample:</span> 170x80px</div>
      <div><span class="show-xs">Desc:</span> Greeny</div>
      <div><span class="show-xs">Price:</span> 0.90</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div><img src="//placehold.it/170x80/aaf"></div>
      <div><span class="show-xs">Color:</span> #aaf</div>
      <div><span class="show-xs">Sample:</span> 170x80px</div>
      <div><span class="show-xs">Desc:</span> Purply</div>
      <div><span class="show-xs">Price:</span> 1.00</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

To recap, I didn't say *Don't use Bootstrap*, I'm just trying to say that it's empowering to know some *best practices*, know how CSS works, how Bootstrap works, and eventually decide what's best for your project.