# Dynamic Table Layout dependng on Screen Size...>

Tags: css, html-table, flexbox, grid, media-queries

Im trying to have a table that renders in two different formats depending on the screen size and I was wondering what's best for the job:

- Table
- Flex
- Grid
- Combination of Flex & Grid
- None of the above and just use lots of Divs with classes and IDs.

The content of the Table will be dynamically updated via JS on the Node js backend and sent back to the client so I need to get the structure and css right first.

what Im trying to achieve is this on Tablets and wider Screens:
[image]

and this on Mobile Screens:
[image]

The Table is straight forward in wide screen mode, but Im not sure how to make Col2 and Col4 wrap around on top of each others.
I suspect moving Col3 in front of Col2 can be done with 'order: 2' Col3 and 'order: 3' for Col2 by using Flex.

Can the layout be changed using a media query and if so, how would one do that?

Happy to use some javascript if it helps but not sure if JS can help with the media query.

This is a codepen of the table in normal format: https://codepen.io/Mickael/pen/MWEarKN

Im just using standing Table html at the moment:

```
<tr>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>Lando Norris</td>
  <td class="drv_num">4</td>
  <td>McLaren F1 Team</td>
  <td>153<span style="visibility: hidden">.0</span></td>
</tr>
```

There's a somewhat helpful answer here using Divs:

[Making table content responsive to screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32938384/making-table-content-responsive-to-screen-size)

but the problem with that one is that is just moves everything on top of each other and doesnt display the Headers.

Any help or pointers with some code to get me started would greatly help.
Cheers,
M.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve got it sorted. The answer was Flex!

If you reduce the width of your browser window to minimal width, it will stack up the rows for Driver and Team neatly!

I’ve still got some work to do on the formatting of the table, like working out the width of the table. (Further suggestions welcome.)

This code shows how using Divs instead of the Table format in my first posting works for the format I want instead of using a table:

```
<div class="table-drivers table-drivers__row">
    <div id="" class="drv-rank">1</div>
    <div id="" class="drv-num">33</div>
    <div class="drv-team__combo">
        <div id="" class="drv-name">Max Verstapen</div>
        <div id="" class="drv-team">Red Bull Racing</div>
    </div>
    <div id="" class="drv-poles">9</div>
    <div id="" class="drv-wins">9</div>
    <div id="" class="drv-points">351.5</div>
</div>
```

[This is all setup in Codepen](https://codepen.io/Mickael/pen/poWjOoY), if it can help someone in the future.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.. I'll take out the second question. As for the code in there, I said rando but it is related... in the first post, I shows how I am displaying the row using table and in the sscond post, how I changed it to a set of Divs instead for the same result, which is related to how I managed to get the format to work using flex and Divs instead.